# General transformation of random variables.

Tags: probability

let $X$,$Y$ are two independent and identically distributed exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$>$0$. $Z$ is another random variable such that $Z$=$\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$. Find the probability density function of $Z$.

Comment: You need to show some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda >0$. Then the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $Z$ is
\begin{eqnarray}
\newcommand{\pr}{{\bf Prob}}
\pr(Z\leq z) &=& \pr(X^2 + Y^2 \leq z^2) = \pr\left(Y \leq \sqrt{z^2-X^2}\right)
\\
&=&
\int_{0}^z \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z^2-x^2}} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dydx
\\
&=&
\int_{0}^z \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z^2-x^2}} f_{X}(x) f_{Y}(y) dydx
\\
&=&
\lambda^2 \int_{0}^z \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z^2-x^2}} e^{-\lambda(x+y)} dydx
\\
&=&
\lambda \int_{0}^z \left.\left( -e^{-\lambda y}\right)\right|_{y=0}^{\sqrt{z^2-x^2}} e^{-\lambda x} dx
\\
&=&
\lambda \int_{0}^z \left(1 - e^{-\lambda \sqrt{z^2-x^2}}\right) e^{-\lambda x} dx
\\
&=&
\lambda \int_{0}^z e^{-\lambda x} dx
-
\lambda \int_{0}^z e^{-\lambda (\sqrt{z^2-x^2}+x)} dx.
\end{eqnarray}

We need to differentiate this with respect to $z$ to obtain the probability density function (PDF). The [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) implies that
\begin{eqnarray}
f_Z(z) &=& \frac{d}{dz} F_Z(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \left(
\lambda \int_{0}^z \left(1 - e^{-\lambda \sqrt{z^2-x^2}}\right) e^{-\lambda x} dx
\right)
\\
&=&
\lambda \int_{0}^z \frac{d}{dz}\left(1 - e^{-\lambda \sqrt{z^2-x^2}}\right) e^{-\lambda x} dx
\\
&=&
\lambda^2 z \int_{0}^z \frac{e^{-\lambda (\sqrt{z^2-x^2}+x)}}{\sqrt{z^2-x^2}} dx.
\end{eqnarray}

If we let $x = z\sin\theta$, then $dx = z\cos\theta d\theta$,
we have
\begin{equation}
f_Z(z) = \lambda^2 z \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-\lambda z (\cos\theta + \sin\theta)} d\theta.
\end{equation}

This is as far as I can go.

A simple sanity check that this satisfies the minimal requirement:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^\infty f_Z(z) dz &=& 
\lambda^2 \int_0^\infty z \int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-\lambda z (\cos\theta + \sin\theta)} d\theta dz
\\
&=&
\lambda^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^\infty z e^{-\lambda z (\cos\theta + \sin\theta)} dz d\theta
\\
&=&
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{(\cos\theta + \sin\theta)^2} d\theta
\\
&=&
\frac{1}{2} \left.\tan(x-\pi/4)\right)|_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2} = 1,
\end{eqnarray}
by [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_both_sine_and_cosine).

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: @SaiSandeepChenna My Pleasure!